# How do I select this class in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, class, puppeteer, selector

Keep in mind I need it to specifically grab the custom-body-copy class along with the body copy class as there are hundreds of body-copys on the page.

```
<div class="row item-row" id="1000017509" data-body-row="" automation-id="itemRows_17">

    <div class="body-copy custom-body-copy" automation-id="itemNumberLabel_17">
           Item&nbsp;879520
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
  const products = await page.$$('.item-row'); 
  
  Promise.all(products.map(async product => {
    let productId = await product.$eval('.body-copy', el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g, '').replace('Item', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

When I add ('.body-copy.custom-body-copy', .....) it throws an error saying (Error: failed to find element matching selector "${selector}"); but it works when used in documentqueryselectorAll().

here are all the lines, the rest are login/clicks to get to the lists page:

```
 const products = await page.$$('.item-row'); 

  Promise.all(products.map(async product => {
    // Inside of each product find product SKU, it's human-readable name, and it's price
    let productId = await product.$eval('.body-copy', el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g, '').replace('Item', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    // if you also want product names, let productName = await product.$eval(".body-copy-link", el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g,' -'));
    let productPrice = await product.$eval('.product_desc_txt div span', el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g, ''));

    // Format them as a csv line
    return productId + ',' + productPrice + ',';
  })).then(lines => {
    // Write the lines to a file, not sure if 'utf-8' is needed
    fs.writeFileSync("products.csv", lines.join('\n'), 'utf-8');
    browser.close();
```

Comment: `.body-copy.custom-body-copy` is a valid selector for that element. Something else could be wrong?

Comment: throw new Error(`Error: failed to find element matching selector "${selector}"`);
                  ^

Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector ".body-copy.custom-body-copy". It's confusing me too...

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your script with the site? It's really hard to debug things like this by guesswork otherwise. Websites can have totally arbitrary behavior: the site might be blocking you, A/B testing, putting elements in iframes, visibility issues, JS adding/removing elements, shadow DOMs, delayed loads.... A query working in dev tools is [no guarantee](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#assuming-browser-devtools-is-the-same-as-node) of it working in Puppeteer.

Comment: One thing that is clear is your `map` doesn't seem to be returning anything, so the `Promise.all` doesn't know about your `$eval` calls. This looks like a selection that can be done more easily with `$$eval` with an inner `querySelector` rather than `$$` and separate `$eval`s for each handle.

Comment: the code works with .body-copy as intended but I need to trim/replace quite a bit vs. if I could just use the more detailed selector. It's on costco business, basically I am scraping my "order list" and adding them into a csv file.